# Bash: Convert string to lowercase AND store changes in updated variable

Tags: bash

In my bash script, I want to take the response and make it lower case to anticipate and avoid errors.

However, when I convert to my `response` to lower case, I can't seem to store that change in the variable.

How can I update the case of an input string and store such that I can compare it later?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e


echo "To reset cluster on existing EKS cluster, we must first destroy the existing cluster."
read -p "Do you want to auto-approve the terraform destroy (y/n): " response

response="$response" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

echo $response

if [ $response = 'y' ]; then
    echo "Destroy is auto-approved."
else 
    echo "Destroy is not auto-approved"
fi
```

Comment: Use command substitution: `$()` to store the output of a command inside a variable , : `response=$(echo "$response" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')`

Comment: You can also extend your condition `if [ "$response" = "y" -o "$response" = "Y" ] ...`

Comment: Another way: before the read, `declare -l response` will automatically lower case it whenever the variable is assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a child process for this task. Simply do a

```
response=${response,,?}
```

The `,,` operator converts each character matched by the glob pattern `?` to upper case.

UPDATE: As Shawn pointed out, and also according to the man-page (which says: *If **pattern** is omitted, it is treated like a ?, which matches every character*), you can omit the question mark and just do a:

```
response=${response,,}
```

Comment: You don't even need the ?. `${response@L}` is another way on recent versions.

Comment: Interesting point! While the `@L` does not work on my bash (perhaps too old), I see that I can indeed drop the `?`.